# Data processing Using Java RegEx

Tags: java, regex

There is sorts of data like

```
Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; R8207 Build/KTU84P)
Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; A51 Build/LMY47V)
Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0; vivo X5Pro D Build/LRX21M)
Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; R8207 Build/KTU84P)
Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; TCL P331M Build/KOT49H)
```

I want get Android vcode like 'Android 4.4.2'. Regex pattern like 
`(\w+/(\d.){1,2}\d)( \(Linux; U; )(Android (\d.){1,2}\d)(.*)` works well.
But when I wrote in Java then it doesnt work. How i write it in Java Regex Syntax. Any advice would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You haven't escaped a `/` after `\w+`. Correct it and check again.

Comment: Just double the backslashes in Java. Like `(\\w+/(?:\\d\\.){1,2}\\d)( \\(Linux; U; )(Android (?:\\d\\.){1,2}\\d)(.*)` and escape the dots that are meant to match literal dots.

Comment: thanks @noob,@Wiktor Stribiżew, but this doesnt work in my hql `select regexp_extract(ua, '(\\w+/(?:\\d\\.){1,2}\\d)( \\(Linux; U; )(Android (?:\\d\\.){1,2}\\d)(.*)', 3)
from vlock_cleaned.vlock_base_active;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax for your Java pattern, in order to find the `Android + version` token:

```
String[] test = {
    "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; R8207 Build/KTU84P)",
    "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; A51 Build/LMY47V)",
    "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0; vivo X5Pro D Build/LRX21M)",
    "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; R8207 Build/KTU84P)",
    "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; TCL P331M Build/KOT49H)" 
};
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Android\\s[\\d.]+");
Pattern wholeStringMatch = Pattern.compile("^.*?(Android\\s[\\d.]+).*?$");
System.out.printf("Matching only necessary pattern...%n%n");
for (String s: test) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group());
    }
}
System.out.printf("%nWhole match...%n%n");
for (String s: test) {
    Matcher m = wholeStringMatch.matcher(s);
    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.printf("Found: %s in %s%n", m.group(1), m.group());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Matching only necessary pattern...

Found: Android 4.4.4
Found: Android 5.1.1
Found: Android 5.0
Found: Android 4.4.4
Found: Android 4.4.2

Whole match...

Found: Android 4.4.4 in Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; R8207 Build/KTU84P)
Found: Android 5.1.1 in Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; A51 Build/LMY47V)
Found: Android 5.0 in Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0; vivo X5Pro D Build/LRX21M)
Found: Android 4.4.4 in Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; R8207 Build/KTU84P)
Found: Android 4.4.2 in Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; TCL P331M Build/KOT49H)
```

**Notes**

- You can replace the `\\w+` element with just static `Android` since you know this is constant.
- Added a whole string match pattern to test against the whole string. As you can see, the token you're looking for is now back-referenced to group `1`

Comment: thank you so much @Mena, it helps me a lot. But I use it in Hive, the regexp_extract(string, pattern, index). the pattern should match the string completely.

Comment: @Ivo you're welcome. Let me amend my answer to match the whole `String`.

Comment: thanks for you patient answer. My problem is solved in your way. Thanks again !

Comment: @Ivo no probs glad it helps :)